# CMS Import/Export. Are there any standards?

Tags: content-management-system

Are there any standard formats for importing or exporting a Content Management System (CMS)?

Answer (score 1):

XML is the closest thing you are going to get.

Since each CMS has their own proprietary way of storing/presenting/managing data, coming up with a common solution for all of them would be a pretty big task.

However, I believe most CMS have a basic XML format that can be leveraged, but you'll need to do some custom work if you want to port from one CMS to another.